Don't understand what pip3 install -e does
New to Python so still trying to understand how it works.
I have a repo which has no requirements or pip file.
I've been asked to upgrade the python version from 3.8 to 3.9.
In the config.json file I've update the numbers to
"Runtime":"python3.9"

I've been told to use pip3 install -e but keep getting an error:
 pip3 install -e  

Usage:  
pip3 install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options]  
pip3 install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options]  
pip3 install [options] [-e] <vcs project url>  
pip3 install (options] [-e] <local project path>  
pip3 install [options] <archive url/path>
  
  -e option requires 1 argument  

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to manually create a requirements.py file before running pip3 install -e?

From the manpage for pip-install:
-e, --editable <path/url>
              Install  a  project  in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS
              url.

              (environment variable: PIP_EDITABLE)

You'll need to give a path or url at the end of the command, such as pip3 install -e ./myproject.
